# Differential of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have this problem where I need to do a differentiation on a integration.

The question is like this:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^{t} \exp(-z^2) dz$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) This says that if $f(z)$ is a well-behaved (say continuous) function, and $a$ is a constant, then
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^t f(z)\,dz=f(t).$$

For fancier versions, you might want to look at the [Leibniz Integral Rule.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)